# OpenSSL 1.1.1g in lib/x86_64/librealm

Tags: react-native, openssl

Defective OpenSSL Version
Your app uses a defective version of the OpenSSL library, which can cause your app to crash. Update to a fixed version of OpenSSL.
Defective versions:
OpenSSL 1.1.1g in lib/x86_64/librealm.so

getting this above error, how can it be resolved in react-native both android and ios.

My project version on realm and reactnative is as follows "realm": "10.9.1" and "react-native": "0.67.1". Trying to update realm to "realm": "12.1.0" and  "react-native": "0.72.0" will this solve the error? any other solutions please.